# UIPageViewController navigates to wrong page with Scroll transition style

Tags: ios6, uipageviewcontroller

My UIPageViewController was working fine in iOS 5. But when iOS 6 came along, I wanted to use the new scroll transition style (UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll) instead of the page curl style. This caused my UIPageViewController to break.

It works fine except right after I've called `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:`. After that, the next time the user scrolls manually by one page, we get the wrong page. What's wrong here?

Comment: Seems to work perfectly in 9.3 though! If you are still interested, could you give it a try on 9.3 to see how things behave on your side, please? Thx.

Comment: @mramosch I am having this problem even on iOS 11.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

My workaround of this bug was to create a block when finished that was setting the same viewcontroller but without animation

```objectivec
__weak YourSelfClass *blocksafeSelf = self;     
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:^(BOOL finished){
            if(finished)
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [blocksafeSelf.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:NULL];// bug fix for uipageview controller
                });
            }
        }];
```

Comment: how to paste it in a code. viewControllers variable is an array with one object which has index (or you store incorrect indexes otherways), so at least it is unclear how to get current index?

Comment: one of these two calls of setViewControllers: is memory leaking the same way as the initial call to set page zero of the UIPageViewController (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156254/uipageviewcontroller-memory-leak). It's not only memeroy leaking, but you can also see more and more viewcontrollers added to the NSArray *childViewControllers readonly property of UIPageViewController. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: There are already multiple rdar tickets, eg. http://openradar.appspot.com/14314073

Comment: This issue still persists in iOS 7.0.3, so a work-around is still necessary. The permanence of the cached view controllers may not be a bug from Apple's perspective.

Comment: UPDATE: If your self has a strong pointer to pageViewController replace the __block with __weak as @matt said. I was just learning objective c at that point i wrote the answer.

Comment: Good job George!
Bad job Apple for this awful class

Comment: OMG. This seems to still exist in iOS 8. Plus the workaround does not seem to work anymore. Anyone else?

Comment: Still here in `iOS 9.2`.

Comment: Sorry guys, but - unless Apple has changed something in 9.3 - what I don't believe - you all must be doing something profoundly wrong. I am doing the weirdest stuff with UIPageViewController in all possible configurations - curl, scroll, animated or not, forward reversed - you name it... - I can't get it to behave anything else than100% correctly. Everything works like a charm and as expected!

Comment: UIPageViewController with two content-views side by side - each holding a UITableView that in every dynamically reused cell holds a UIScrollView or UICollectionView which in turn dynamically reuse cells that hold PDFs that flip pages... etc. - I even call setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion: from within a page turn of a PDF file that is located deep in this hierarchy and let it change its own childViewController underneath and can't get UIPageViewController to crash or behave somewhat off of the regular expected...

Comment: Could someone, who has had problems in the past, give it a try on 9.3 to see how things behave, please? Thx.

Comment: @mramosch I haven't used this earlier, but the bug exists on iOS 10.3.

Comment: This bug still exists in iOS 12.1, but i could only reproduce this using an iPhone(Real and Simulator), but i could not reproduce this using an iPad(Real and Simulator)

Comment: iOS 14.5, bug still here

Comment: iOS 17.1.1, still here 

Answer (score 64):

This is actually a bug in UIPageViewController. It occurs only with the scroll style (UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll) and only after calling `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` *with animated:YES*. Thus there are two workarounds:

1. Don't use UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll.
2. Or, if you call `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:`, use only `animated:NO`.

To see the bug clearly, call `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` and then, in the interface (as user), navigate left (back) to the preceding page manually. You will navigate back to the wrong page: not the preceding page at all, but the page you were on when `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` was called.

The reason for the bug appears to be that, when using the scroll style, UIPageViewController does some sort of internal caching. Thus, after the call to `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:`, it fails to clear its internal cache. It thinks it knows what the preceding page is. Thus, when the user navigates leftward to the preceding page, UIPageViewController *fails to call the dataSource method `pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController:`*, or calls it with the wrong current view controller.

I have posted a movie that clearly demonstrates how to see the bug:

http://www.apeth.com/PageViewControllerBug.mov

**EDIT** This bug will probably be **fixed** in iOS 8.

**EDIT** For another interesting workaround for this bug, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21624169/341994

Comment: Yea I have this bug now too. It seems to cache a view controller on each side of the current.

Comment: The bug is still present in iOS7

Comment: Argh. Just spent an hour or so trying to figure out why this was happening. Fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: this bug still present in iOS8

Comment: Yes bug is still there and setting animation to NO doesn't have any effect.

Comment: setting the animation to 'no' seemed to do the trick for me in iOS 8.2

Comment: Seems to work perfectly in 9.3 though! Could someone, who has had problems in the past, give it a try on 9.3 to see how things behave, please? Thx.

Comment: This bug is still present in iOS 12.4 (simulator) atleast. And setting it to false did solve the problem.

Comment: iOS 15.1 - the bug is still in place) Setting animated to false do solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 12 the problem described in the original question seems to be almost fixed. I came to this question because I experienced it in my particular setup, in which it does still happen, hence the word "almost" here.

The setup I experienced this issue was: 
1) the app was opened via a deep link
2) based on the link the app had to switch to a particular tab and open a given item there via push
3) described issue happened only when the target tab was not previously selected by user (so that UIPageViewController was supposed to animate to that tab) and only when `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` had `animated = true`
4) after the push returning back to the view controller containing the UIPageViewController, the latter was found to be a big mess - it was presenting completely wrong view controllers, even though debugging showed everything was fine on the logic level

I supposed that the root of the problem was that I was pushing view controller very quick after `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` called, so that the UIPageViewController had no chance to finish something (maybe animation, or caching, or something else).

Simply giving UIPageViewController some spare time by delaying my programmatic navigation in UI via

```
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1) { ... }
```

fixed the issue for me. And it also made the programmatic opening of the linked item more user friendly visually.

Hope this helps someone in similar situation.

Comment: Thanks for this contribution!

Answer (score 0):

This bug still exists in iOS9. I am using the same workaround that George Tsifrikas posted above, but a Swift version:

```swift
pageViewController.setViewControllers([page], direction: direction, animated: true) { done in
    if done {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.pageViewController.setViewControllers([page], direction: direction, animated: false, completion: {done in })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have no chance to get a device pre 9.3 - but on a second generation iPad2 (not Air2 !!!) with iOS 9.3 everything works as expected in all possible configurations. See above my comment to the accepted answer...

Comment: Could someone, who has had problems in the past, give it a try on 9.3 to see how things behave, please? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Because pageviewVC call multi childVC when swipe it. But we just need last page that visible.

In my case, I need to change index for segmented control when change pageView.

Hope this help someone :)

```swift
extension ViewController: UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        guard let pageView = pageViewController.viewControllers?.first as? ChildViewController else { return }
        segmentedControl.set(pageView.index)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple workaround in Swift: Just reset the UIPageViewController's datasource.  This apparently clears its cache and works around the bug.  Here's a method to go directly to a page without breaking subsequent swipes. In the following, m_pages is an array of your view controllers. I show how to find currPage (the index of the current page) below.

```swift
func goToPage(_ index: Int, animated: Bool)
{
    if m_pages.count > 0 && index >= 0 && index < m_pages.count && index != currPage
    {
        var dir: UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection
        if index < currPage
        {
            dir = UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection.reverse
        }
        else
        {
            dir = UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection.forward
        }

        m_pageViewController.setViewControllers([m_pages[index]], direction: dir, animated: animated, completion: nil)
        delegate?.tabDisplayed(sender: self, index: index)
        m_pageViewController.dataSource = self;
    }
}
```

How to find the current page:

```swift
var currPage: Int
{
    get
    {
        if let currController = m_pageViewController.viewControllers?[0]
        {
            return m_pages.index(of: currController as! AtomViewController) ?? 0
        }

        return 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

***STATEMENT:***

It seems that Apple has spotted that developers are using UIPageViewController in very different applications that go way beyond the
originally intended ones Apple based their design-choices on in the first place. Rather than using it in a gesture driven linear fashion 
PVC is often used to programmatically jump to random
positions within a structured environment. So they have enhanced their implementation of UIPageViewController and the class is now calling both DataSource
callbacks

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

after setting a new contentViewController on UIPageViewController with

```
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];
```

even if an animated turn of pages rather suggests a linear progress in an e.g. page hierarchy like a book or PDF with consecutive pages. Although - I doubt that Apple from a HIG standpoint
is very fond of seeing PVC  being used this way, but - it doesn't break backwards compatibility, it was an easy fix, so - they eventually did it. Actually it is just one more call of one of the two DataSource methods that is absolutely unnecessary in a linear environment where pages (ViewControllers) have already been cashed for later use.

However, even if this enhancement might come in very handy for certain use-cases the initial behavior of the class is NOT to be considered a bug. The fact that a lot of developers do - also in other
posts on SO that accuse UIPageViewController of misbehavior - rather emphasizes a widely spread misconception of its design, purpose and functionality.

Without trying to offend any of my fellow developers here in this great facility I nonetheless decided not to remove my initial 'disquisition' that clearly explains to the OP the mechanics of PVC and why his assumption is wrong that he has to deal with a bug here.

This might also be of use for any other fellow developer too who struggles with some intricacies in the implementation of UIPageViewController!

---

***ORIGINAL ANSWER:***

After having read all the answers over and over again - included the
accepted one - there is just one more thing left to say...

The design of `UIPageViewController` is absolutely **FLAWLESS** and all the
hacks you submit in order to circumvent an alleged bug is nothing but
remedies for your own faulty assumptions because you goofed it up in the
first place!!!

**THERE IS NO BUG AT ALL!** You are just fighting the framework. I'll explain why!

---

There is so much talk about page numbers and indices! These are concepts the
controller knows ***NOTHING*** about! The only thing it knows is - it is showing
some content (btw. provided by you as a *dataViewController*) and that it can
do something like a right/left animation in order to imitate a page turn.
`CURL` or `SCROLL`...!!!

In the *pageViewController*'s world there only exists a current `SPACE` (let's call
it just this way to avoid confusion with pages and indices).

When you initially set a *pageViewController* it only minds about this very `SPACE`.
Only when you start panning its view it starts asking its `DataSource` what it
eventually should display in case a left/right flip should happen. When you start
panning to the left the PVC asks first for the `BEFORE-SPACE` and then for the
`AFTER-SPACE`, in case you start to the right it does it the other way round.

After the completed animation (a new `SPACE` is displayed by the PVC's view) the
PVC considers this `SPACE` as its new center of the universe and while it is at it, it
asks the `DataSource` about the one it still does not know anything about. In case of
a completed turn to the right it wants to know about the new `AFTER` space and in
case of a completed turn to the left it asks for a new `BEFORE` space.

The old `BEFORE` space (from before the animation) is in case of a completed turn to
the right completely obsolete and gets deallocated as soon as possible. The old `center`
is now the new `BEFORE` and the former `AFTER` is the new `center`. Everything just
shifted one step to the right.

So - no talk of '*which page*' or '*whatever index*' - just simply - is there a `BEFORE` or
an `AFTER` space. If you return NIL to one of the `DataSource` callbacks the PVC just
assumes it is at one extreme of your *`range of SPACES`*. If you return NIL to both
callbacks it assumes it is showing the *`one and only SPACE`* there is and will never
ever again call a `DataSource` callback anymore! The logic is up to you! You define
pages and indices in your code! Not the PVC!!!

---

For the user of the class there are two means of interacting with the PVC.

- `A pan-gesture that indicates whether a turn to the BEFORE/AFTER space is desired`
- `A method - namely setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:`

This method does exactly the same than the pan gesture is doing. You are indicating the
direction (e.g. `UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionBackward/Forward`)
for the animation - if there is one intended - which in other words just means -> going to
`BEFORE` or `AFTER`...

Again - no mentioning of indices, page-numbers etc....!!!

It is just a programmatically way of achieving the same a gesture would!
And the PVC is doing right by showing the old content again when moving back
to the left after having moved to the right in the first place. Remember
- it is just showing content (that you provide) in a structured way - which is a *`'single page turn'`* by design!!!

That is the concept of a page turn - or BOOK, if you like that term better!

Just because you goof it up by submitting PAGE 8 after PAGE 1 doesn't mean the PVC
cares at all about your twisted opinion of how a book should work. And the user of your
apps neither. Flipping to the right and back to the left should definitely result in reaching
the original page - IF done with an animation. And it is up to YOU to correct the goof by
finding a solution for the disaster. Don't blame it on the *`UIPageViewController`*. It is doing
its job perfectly!

Just ask yourself - would you do the same thing with a `PAGE-CURL` animation? NO ?
Well, neither should you with a `SCROLL` animation!!! An animated page turn is a page turn and only a page turn!
In either mode!
And if you decide to tear out PAGE 2 to PAGE 7 of your BOOK that's perfectly fine!
But just don't expect *`UIPageViewController`* to invent a non-existing PAGE 7 when turning back to the recent page unless YOU tell it that things have changed...

---

If you really want to achieve an uncoordinated jump to elsewhere, well - do it without an
animation! In most cases this will not be very elegant but - it's possible... -

And the PVC even plays nicely along! When jumping to a new `SPACE` without animation
it will ask you further down the road for both - the `BEFORE` and `AFTER` controller. So your application-logic can keep up with the PVC...

But with an animation you are always conveying - move to the previous/next space (`BEFORE -
AFTER`). So logically there is no need at all for the PVC to ask again about a space it already
knows about when animating page turns!!!

If you wanna see PAGE 7 when flipping back to the left after having animated from PAGE 1
to the right - well, I would say - that's definitely your very own problem!

---

And just in case you are looking for a better solution than the 'completion-block' hack from
the accepted answer (because with it you are doing work beforehand for something that might
possibly not even get used further down the road) use the gesture recognizer delegate:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
```

Set your PVC's DataViewController here (without animation) if you really intend to go back
left to PAGE 7 and the `DataSource` will be asked for `BEFORE` and `AFTER` and you can submit
whatever page you like! With a flag or ivar that you should have stashed away when doing your uncontrolled
jump from PAGE 1 to 8 this should be no problem...

---

And when people keep on complaining about a bug in the PVC - doing 2 page turns when it is
supposed to do 1 turn only - point them to this article.

Same problem - triggering an un-animated *setViewControllers:* method within the transition gesture
will cause exactly the same havoc. You think you set the new center - the DataSource is asked
for the new `BEFORE - AFTER` dataController - you reset your index count... - Well, that seems OK...

But - after all that business the PVC ends its transition/animation and wants to know about the 
next (still unknown to it) dataViewController (`BEFORE` or `AFTER`) and also triggers the `DataSource`. That's totally justified ! It needs to know where in its small `BEFORE - CENTER - AFTER`
world it is and be prepared for the next turn.

But your program-logic adds another index++ count to its logic and suddenly got 2 page turns !!!
And that is one off from where you think you are.

And *YOU* have to account for that! Not *`UIPageViewController`* !!!

---

That is exactly the point of the DataSourceProtocol only having two methods! It wants to be as generic as possible - leaving you the space and freedom to define your own logic and not being stuck with somebody else's special ideas and use-cases! The logic is completely up to you. And only because you find functions like

```
- (DataViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index storyboard:(UIStoryboard *)storyboard position:(GSPositionOfDataViewController)position;
- (NSUInteger)indexOfViewController:(DataViewController *)viewController;
```

in all the copy/pasted sample applications in the cloud doesn't necessarily mean that you have to eat that pre-cook food! Extend them any way you like! Just look above - in my signature you will find a *`'position:'`* argument! I extended this to know later on if a completed page turn was a right or a left turn. Because the delegate unfortunately just tells you whether your turn completed or not! It doesn't tell you about the direction! But this sometimes matters for index-counting, depending on your application's need...

Go crazy - they are your's...

HAPPY CODING !!!

Comment: Well I guess that's why people keep telling us that the bug -> still persists in iOS 7.0.3 -> seems to still exist in iOS 8 -> Still here in iOS 9.2 etc. -  Your 2012 movie that demonstrates the bug -'http://www.apeth.com/PageViewControllerBug.mov' - is showing a behavior that is still the same today and will be forever because it is accurate. I see the slices of history very well - and from the early beginnings all accusations (at least in this thread) against UIPageViewController have been unjustified. There are some serious bugs in the class but definitely not the ones you are talking about

Comment: I am sorry for my direct harsh language - no offense intended - seriously... ;-) - People just have to understand how UIPageViewController really works and is designed to be used before complaining and filing radars...

Comment: So what by the way was the bug you mentioned that got fixed after iOS 6 - if you don't mind spending a little time in complaining. I am really curious - is it mentioned here or in another post ? Got a link for me, please?

Comment: "is showing a behavior that is still the same today" no it isn't. I have the original test project. The bug did occur in iOS 6, but the very same code linked and run against iOS 10 behaves differently (and correctly). Look, this really was a bug, acknowledged by Apple and fixed. Please take your long essay away. You're just wrong. You weren't there at the time and you don't know.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your time! So just to clarify - you are saying that in iOS10 (and exactly repeating the steps you do in your video) after programmatically having set your contentViewController (animated:YES) to PAGE 8 you are (with a pan-gesture) going back to PAGE 7 because -> after Apple's bug-fix now both DataSource callbacks (BEFORE - AFTER) are getting called and you now finally have the hook to submit PAGE 7 in the BEFORE callback without having to use any other form of additional function call? Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks for helping out - I made a new sample project with the Xcode PageView template and saw that Apple has enhanced their class by calling both DataSource callbacks now! I clarified this at the very beginning of my post so that people know about this enhancement. Cheers.

Comment: @matt Your linked example project works without issues on iOS 11, but the caching bug is still not fully fixed. When I modify your example so that `jumpTo8` is called from a modal view controller and insert '[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` as the first line of `jumpTo8`, the previously visible page (instead of page 7) will appear when swiping back. This case can be fixed by calling `setViewControllers` with `animated:NO`, since the animation would not be visible anyway.