# UiPageViewController disable left slide

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

I added in my app a tutorial section that consists of an UIPageViewController.

The problem is that i don't want the user to be able to return to previous steps.

I tried returning nil for previous controller but it does not work.

Can someone give me a hint?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to disable previous steps, maybe `UIPageViewController` isn't the best choice as it has the implied functionality of being able to move left and right.

Comment: See discussion here : 

> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426728/uipageviewcontroller-direction-only-forward

Comment: Thanks for the reply...i used the curl option and now it works.