# How to handle backward scrolling in UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I have used a UIPageViewController having 5 view controller for scrolling. Now in my case I just want user to go forward only not backward.
Means if I'm on 1st view controller and I swiped on screen, I'll be navigated to 2nd view controller. Now I can't go back to 1st view controller.

Attaching the code here.

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    return nil;
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[MyViewController1 class]]) {
        return [self viewControllerAtIndex:1];
    } else if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[MyViewController2 class]]) {
        return [self viewControllerAtIndex:2];
    } else if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[MyViewController3 class]]) {
        return [self viewControllerAtIndex:3];
    } else if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[MyViewController4 class]]) {
        return [self viewControllerAtIndex:4];
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Any Idea???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426728/uipageviewcontroller-direction-only-forward

Comment: no success. Any other idea or link?

Comment: Remove previous view controller inside this method if complete == YES - (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed

Answer (score 0):

You can do a work around for this, in side `didFinishAnimating` delegate method set currentViewController without animation

```
    - (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed
    {
    if (completed){
         __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          [weakSelf.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[vc] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:NULL];
         });
       }
    }
```

For more detail on this issue visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220289/removing-a-view-controller-from-uipageviewcontroller/16308151#16308151)

Comment: Its crashing the application.