# UIPageViewController leaking objects

Tags: ios, xamarin

I been doing some memory profiling, and I cannot figure out why some objects are not being garbage collected - it's only a problem when using UIPageViewController, and I think it might be related to [UIPageViewController memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156254/uipageviewcontroller-memory-leak) but there is no final answer in that thread.

In another viewcontroller I do

```
var vc = new PageController;
NavigationController.pushViewController(vc, true);
vc = null;
```

The code saves a WeakReference for the PageController object, and for Page0 and Page1.

Then I hit "Back". As far as I know there should be no references to PageController, Page0 or Page1 anymore.

I the force the Garbage Collector to do its stuff:

```
GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Afterways I then check my WeakReferences, and all three objects are still alive. I only see this with UIPageViewController. With UIViewController or UITableViewController all WeakReferenced objects disappear when I hit back, and do a full GC.

This is Xamarin.IOS in VS2013, so unfortunately I dont have access to any real memory profiler, so I cannot see what keeps those objects alive.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class PageController : UIPageViewController
{
    public PageController()
        : base(UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.Scroll, UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation.Horizontal)
    { }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        SetViewControllers(new[] {new Page0()}, UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, true, null);
        WeakDataSource = new xSource();
    }

    public class xSource : UIPageViewControllerDataSource
    {
        public override UIViewController GetPreviousViewController(UIPageViewController pageViewController,
            UIViewController referenceViewController)
        {
            if (referenceViewController is Page1) return new Page0();
            return null;
        }

        public override UIViewController GetNextViewController(UIPageViewController pageViewController,
            UIViewController referenceViewController)
        {
            if (referenceViewController is Page0) return new Page1();
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public class Page0 : UIViewController
{
    public Page0() { }
}

public class Page1 : UIViewController
{
    public Page1()
    { }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to answer my own question:

The problem was not directly the UIPageViewController, rather it was the use of a derived type, which messes up garbage collection.

You need to call this.navigationController.Dispose() from ViewWillDisappear.

More info: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/12005/uiviewcontroller-never-garbage-collected-with-derived-uiview