# Programmatically set UIPageViewController Transition Style to Scroll

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I am using Xcode 6 and implementing `UIPageViewController` for my app. I followed [appcoda's tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/), and everything works except the page indicators. This is because I cannot set the transition style of `UIPageViewController` to scroll.

Graphically, when I click on the `PageViewController`, the tab shows View Controller instead of Page View Controller like `appcoda` (See its image below)

[image]

This is what mine looks like:

[image]

And yes, my custom class is set to: `UIPageViewController` as it is in the tutorial.
[image]

Programmatically, I try to set the transition style with:

```
    self.pageViewController.transitionStyle = UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.Scroll
```

but it fails to build, telling me that it *Could not find member transition style*. 
One last weird thing I would like to point out is that if I just write `self.pageViewController.transitionStyle`, it builds successfully, but it still uses the `Page Curl` Transition.

Could anyone help me? I am using Swift, Xcode 6, and developing on the iOS 8 SDK.

Comment: Try clearing custom class and setting it back.

Comment: Tried already, but thanks.

Comment: When you clear the custom class, is the default class UIPageViewController or UIViewController, if latter it means you didn't use the correct story board object.

Comment: I upload sample code in swift5 with information of other people.
https://github.com/sun5022/UIPageViewController

Answer (score 43):

The issue is that when you create a UIPageViewController inside a Container, the container is first created with a UIViewController, and that s the controller you see your options for.

In order to fix it you have to delete UIViewController where you set your custom UIPageViewController. Then drag UIPageViewController from the controls picker and hook up the embed segue from the container to that controller, then you can set your custom pager controller as well as set transition to scroll.

Comment: Thats exactly it! I came here to answer this, but you already did it. :) Upvote for you. All other answers work, but the underlying problem was this.  :)

Comment: This is the correct solution and should be accepted as such.

Comment: This is the real answer, the others are good lazy workarounds!

Comment: You're a life saver.

Answer (score 42):

You're getting an error because `transitionStyle` is a readonly property. If you want to set the transition style of the page controller programmatically, it can only be done during initialization with the method:

```
init(transitionStyle style: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle, navigationOrientation navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation, options options: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) { ... }
```

More info in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPageViewController/initWithTransitionStyle%3anavigationOrientation%3aoptions%3a).

Comment: This seems like it would work, but I am having trouble implementing it. Where exactly would I put this? In appcoda's tutorial, I instantiate the UIPageViewController in my ViewController with: `self.pageViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as UIPageViewController`. (Sorry about these basic questions, I am learning Swift and Objective C and iOS development in general at the same time)

Comment: @sameetandpotatoes That's alright; and if you're creating your page view controller in storyboard, you don't actually have to call this method yourself. If you were creating your page view controller completely programmatically, you would use this initializer, but since you're using storyboard, just select the transition style the way you're already doing it.

Comment: but that's the source of my problem. I am doing it in storyboard, but when I go to select the transition style, there is no option for Scroll because Xcode thinks its a View Controller and not a Page View Controller.

Comment: There is specifically a UIPageViewController icon in Interface Builder. Are you using this as opposed to dragging out a UIViewController and changing it's custom class to UIPageViewController?

Comment: That was my issue: I embedded one in a container.  I had to delete the autogenerated VC and segue, and recreate them using the proper object.  You can't just change the class type.  Which is lame.

Comment: @jeffamaphone I have the same problem: It's embedded in a container and I don't have any point where I can change the transition style

Comment: If you embed it in IB as a `UIPageViewController` there should be an option to change the transition style.  If you took a `UIViewController` which was already embedded and just set the custom class, the option won't be there.  Delete what you have, drag out the proper class from the object selector, and re-wire the embed segue.

Answer (score 31):

### **Swift 3.0**

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
}
```

Comment: I don't feed comfortable doing this... aren't we triggering the end of the world not calling the init(coder:) initializer?

Comment: Thank you It works for swift 5.0 too. This solution works to whom use the UIPageViewController in a nib file or the .storyboard

Answer (score 17):

in ios 8 swift3

```
override init(transitionStyle style: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation, options: [String : Any]? = nil) {
        super.init(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: options)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

Comment: Please check Marcin Deszczynski's answer. :)

Comment: Good solution here working without storyboard.  Simple and to the point.

Comment: THIS is the right answer. Applied in Xcode 9.1 & Swift 4

Answer (score 11):

This is how I solved this problem in Swift 2.0
1. Created a class which is subclass of class UIPageViewController

```
    import UIKit
    
    class OPageViewController: UIPageViewController {
        
        override init(transitionStyle style: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation, options: [String : AnyObject]?) {

           // Here i changed the transition style: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.Scroll           
            super.init(transitionStyle: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.Scroll, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation.Horizontal, options: options)
        }
    
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
    
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        }
    
    
    }
```

2.Than i just used it :D

```
pageController = OPageViewController()
pageController.dataSource = self
pageController.setViewControllers(NSArray(object: vc) as? [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
pageController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, container.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, container.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 10):

I know this a little bit late, but I just had the same problem and realized that it was originated because I was using a simple UIViewController, even when my custom view controller class inherits from an UIPageViewController, aparently the graphic menu of xcode doesn't recognize it.

The solution was to delete in story board the view controller and drag a PageViewController to replace it. This will have the graphic menu with the scroll option.

Answer (score 10):

### Xcode 7.1 & Swift 2

All other solutions did not fully work for me at the latest Swift, especially since my class also inherits from UIPageViewControllerDataSource and UIPageViewControllerDelegate.

To set the PageViewController transition to .Scroll just add these 2 methods to your class:

```
override init(transitionStyle style: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation, options: [String : AnyObject]?) {
    super.init(transitionStyle: .Scroll, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: options)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Comment: My 1st init is never getting called. UIPageViewController is declared in storyboard

Answer (score 10):

Swift 5 & 4:
Just put this 2 functions before viewDidLoad() in your pageview VC

```
override init(transitionStyle style: UIPageViewController.TransitionStyle, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewController.NavigationOrientation, options: [UIPageViewController.OptionsKey : Any]? = nil) {
    super.init(transitionStyle: .pageCurl, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Comment: `transitionStyle: .scroll`

Answer (score 8):

Easiest way to do this programmatically in Swift 2.0 (without subclassing):

```
class PageViewController: UIPageViewController {

     override init(transitionStyle style: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle, navigationOrientation navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation, options options: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
          super.init(transitionStyle: .Scroll, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: options) 
     }

}
```

Comment: This _is_ subclassing.

Comment: Please check Marcin Deszczynski's answer. :)

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me . Because if I override init for transitionStyle , it never gets called if you have set  pageViewController in a container view in Storyboard.

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
    }
```

Comment: THE ACTUALLY CORRECT ANSWER!

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4 programmatically set the transition style of UIPageViewController**

This is straight from 'UIPageViewController.h' line 61-97

Just put this before viewDidLoad() in your UIPageViewController() class

```
    override init(transitionStyle style: 
UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation, options: [String : Any]? = nil) {
            super.init(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
        }
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5

```
class OnboardingController: UIPageViewController {

    override init(transitionStyle style: UIPageViewController.TransitionStyle, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewController.NavigationOrientation, options: [UIPageViewController.OptionsKey : Any]? = nil) {
        super.init(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Comment: Lance, in your excellent code, there's no reason you wouldn't also set it in the STORYBOARD call.  (Note that these days, bizarrely, you CAN NOT set simply "scroll" in storyboard - for some reason they removed it from IB. You must set it in code as per your code.)  I added it to your answer, of course edit as you wish cheers

Comment: @Fattie Thanks for the edit! Honestly I haven’t used Storyboard in years. I do everything programmatically so it’s better that you updated my answer so that it helps the next person who does you Storyboard. Cheers!!!

Comment: heh right on Lance!  cheers !

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug with UIPageViewController

You can read an explanation of the cause in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939280/uipageviewcontroller-navigates-to-wrong-page-with-scroll-transition-style) SO question and more comprehensively in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220289/removing-a-view-controller-from-uipageviewcontroller) one.

I used the AppCoda Tutorial as well to get a handle on PageViewControllers. Another SO user actually wrote a gist that solved the problem for me in a way that I didn't have to change a line of code in my own project. Just drop AVC in to your project and call that instead of UIPageViewController in your code.

Paul de Lange's [AlzheimerViewController](https://gist.github.com/paul-delange/5582394/download#).

Answer (score 1):

**In swift 5**

In the Page view Controller you can write following code

TransitionStyle scroll

```
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
    }
```

For   transitionStyle curl

```
 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(transitionStyle: .pageCurl, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
    }
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

swift 3 xcode 8 in

class ...: UIPageViewController {

```
override var transitionStyle: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle {
    return .scroll
}

override var navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation {
    return .horizontal
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions below worked for Swift 5.
here is what worked for me, in my case i needed the view controller to be presented on top of the other view controller with low opacity background:

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

    self.setupView()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.setupView()
}

private func setupView() {
    self.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    self.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
}
```